# Bash - variable variables

Tags: bash, variables

I have the variable `$foo="something"` and would like to use:

```
bar="foo"; echo $($bar)
```

to get "something" echoed.

Comment: Please see [BashFAQ/006](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006). Also, you shouldn't try to use a dollar sign on the left side of an assignment.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

In bash, you can use `${!variable}` to use variable variables.

```
foo="something"
bar="foo"
echo "${!bar}"

# something
```

Comment: in `sh` it says bad substitution. Any idea how to do it in `sh`?

Comment: how does this work with arrays?

Comment: @Edison `foo1="something1"
foo2="something2"
bar[0]="foo1"
bar[1]="foo2"
echo ${!bar[0]}
echo ${!bar[1]}
`

Comment: I ended up doing something like "
 read -a subNames <<< $(eval "echo \${$rootName[@]}")
 for subName in "${subNames[@]}""

Comment: @Edison see also [my recent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25167219/2908724).

Comment: What do if bar somting like  bar=$(${LINEDATA[3]}|iconv -f "windows-1251" -t "UTF-8") ?

Answer (score 9):

`eval echo \"\$$bar\"` would do it.

Comment: Be aware of the [security implications of `eval`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048).

Comment: This solution has the benefit of being POSIX-compatible for non-Bash shells (for example, lightweight environments like embedded systems or Docker containers).

And you can assign the value to another variable like so:
```sh
var=$(eval echo \"\$$bar\")
```

Answer (score 9):

The accepted answer is great.  However, @Edison asked how to do the same for arrays.  The trick is that you want your variable holding the "[@]", so that the array is expanded with the "!". Check out this function to dump variables:

```
$ function dump_variables() {
    for var in "$@"; do
        echo "$var=${!var}"
    done
}
$ STRING="Hello World"
$ ARRAY=("ab" "cd")
$ dump_variables STRING ARRAY ARRAY[@]
```

This outputs:

```
STRING=Hello World
ARRAY=ab
ARRAY[@]=ab cd
```

When given as just `ARRAY`, the first element is shown as that's what's expanded by the `!`.  By giving the `ARRAY[@]` format, you get the array and all its values expanded.

Comment: Good point about handling arrays.  Any idea how to get the *indices* of an array?  The [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) indicates this is normally done with `${!ARRAY[@]}`, which seems to conflict with the variable indirection syntax.

Comment: @dimo414 Yeah, getting the keys through indirection is trickier. You'd have to pass just the name, then do the expansion in the method: `local -a 'keys=("${!'"$var"'[@]}")'`.  The [indirection article on Bash Hackers](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arrays#indirection) goes into more depth.

Answer (score 1):

To make it more clear how to do it with arrays:

```
arr=( 'a' 'b' 'c' )
# construct a var assigning the string representation 
# of the variable (array) as its value:
var=arr[@]         
echo "${!var}"
```