# Argument manipulation in bash function

Tags: bash, arguments

I need to manipulate arguments given to a function, to make it more compact.

e.g.

```
hoax_one=1
hoax_boo=5

get_sum(){
    echo $1
    echo $2
}
```

..but instead of giving:
    get_sum "$hoax_one" "$hoax_boo", to give just get_sum hoax.

I was thinking of something like that:

```
get_sum(){
    echo $1_one
    echo $2_boo
}
```

but it outputs

```
hoax_one
hoax_boo
```

and not its values (declared before)!

Is it possible? There is a big database with hoax prefixes (and other ones), i need to just run the get_sum with a single word...:/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make variable variable as suggested here: [Bash - variable variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757380/bash-variable-variables)

```
var="${1}_one"
echo ${!var}
```

Comment: still echoes string and not value though