# Assign command line argument to variable in shell script

Tags: shell, unix, command-line-arguments

```
#!/bin/sh

a=0

while [ $a -lt $# ]
do
   var_no=$a
    echo "var_no value is $var_no"
    dir_no=`expr $a + 1`
    dirname=$dir_no
    echo "dirname value is $dirname" # $n is the command line arg   
    if [ -d $dirname ]
        then
        echo " $dirname exists"
        else
        echo "[$dirname]  not exist"
        mkdir $dirname;
    fi
   a=`expr $a + 1`
done
```

when i am try to assign from arguments to a shell variable it's not showing the expected output as shown below.

Output is

```
$sh while.sh xyz yzx
var_no value is 0
dirname value is 1 ------ but expecting xyz
This dirname 1 exists 
var_no value is 1 
dirname value is 2 ------ but expecting yzx
This dirname 2 exists
```

Comment: And your question is .... ?

Comment: $1 will give first argument here it is xyz, i need the $1,$2,$3... values  but when i coded like this i'm getting dirname value is 1 ------ but expecting xyz will you please help to complete this task.. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you update your title so it gives readers some idea what you're asking? "Shell scripting" is far too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line: `dirname=$dir_no`

You're clobbering your directory name with the directory number.  This will *not* get you the value of `$1`, `$2`, etc.  This gets you a number (`1`, `2`, etc).

If you want the variables `$1`, `$2`, etc, you need to use a [variable variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757380/bash-variable-variables):

```
dirname=${!dir_no}
```

Comment: Thanks Llama , i just added a line echo ${!dir_no} to code , but when i'm trying to execute its throwing an error "while.sh: 11: while.sh: Bad substitution" in absence of echo ${!dir_no} its executing but not getting the desired output.

Comment: @user3686069 - Do you have Bash available as a shell? Try changing your first line to `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: I have the Bash Shell , i changed the first line to #!/bin/bash even i'm getting the same error, what will be the cause ?

Comment: I migrated my code to some other machine ... Now it's under my requirement.. Thanks all. :)