# How to check if multiple variables are defined or not in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I want to check, if multiple variable are set or not, if set then only execute the script code, otherwise exit.

something like:

```
if [ ! $DB=="" && $HOST=="" && $DATE==""  ]; then
  echo "you did not set any variable"
   exit 1;
else
  echo "You are good to go"
fi
```

Comment: for check variable has value or not [ -z $a -a -z $b -a -z $c ] && echo "has not value" || echo " ok good to go!"

Answer (score 117):

You can use `-z` to test whether a variable is unset or empty:

```
if [[ -z $DB || -z $HOST || -z $DATE ]]; then
  echo 'one or more variables are undefined'
  exit 1
fi

echo "You are good to go"
```

As you have used the [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) tag, I've used an extended test `[[`, which means that I don't need to use quotes around my variables. I'm assuming that you need all three variables to be defined in order to continue. The `exit` in the `if` branch means that the `else` is superfluous.

The standard way to do it in any POSIX-compliant shell would be like this:

```
if [ -z "$DB" ] || [ -z "$HOST" ] || [ -z "$DATE" ]; then
  echo 'one or more variables are undefined'        
  exit 1
fi
```

The important differences here are that each variable check goes inside a separate test and that double quotes are used around each parameter expansion.

Comment: Thanks! I guess you could also use `-o` to combine the tests in a single predicate, rather than using || and three separate `[` calls?

Comment: @BeeOnRope The recommendation is to [avoid using `-a` and `-o`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/utilities/test.html) (see the _Application Usage_ section), especially when dealing with variables that could be user-defined.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the "quotes" difference. I didn't even see that diff in my code :(

Answer (score 22):

If you are ok with writing a function for this purpose, it can be pretty convenient.

This solution uses the `${!VAR_NAME}` syntax to check whether the variable is empty and has the added benefit of telling you which variable names are empty.

```
check_vars()
{
    var_names=("$@")
    for var_name in "${var_names[@]}"; do
        [ -z "${!var_name}" ] && echo "$var_name is unset." && var_unset=true
    done
    [ -n "$var_unset" ] && exit 1
    return 0
}

# Usage for this case
check_vars DB HOST DATE
echo "You are good to go"
```

Answer (score 4):

I wound up using [variable-variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757380/bash-variable-variables) to loop through an easily managed HEREDOC list of variable names:

```
# Ensure non-empty values.
# Loop through HEREDOC, test variable-variable isn't blank.
while read var; do
  [ -z "${!var}" ] && { echo "$var is empty or not set. Exiting.."; exit 1; }
done << EOF
KUBE_NAMESPACE
DOCKER_REGISTRY
DOCKER_DEPLOY_USER
DOCKER_DEPLOY_PASSWORD
DOCKER_DEPLOY_EMAIL
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check it also by put the variables name in a file

```
DB=myDB
HOST=myDB
DATE=myDATE
```

then test them if currently `empty` or `unset`

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r line; do
    var=`echo $line | cut -d '=' -f1`
    test=$(echo $var)
    if [ -z "$(test)" ]; then 
        echo 'one or more variables are undefined'
        exit 1
    fi
done <var.txt
echo "You are good to go"
```

Answer (score 1):

Nice solution from @joe.still !
improvement is to exit after checking all variables

```
i=0
while read var; do
  [ -z "${!var}" ] && { echo "$var is empty or not set. Exiting.."; let i=i+1; }
done << EOF
KUBE_NAMESPACE
DOCKER_REGISTRY
DOCKER_DEPLOY_USER
DOCKER_DEPLOY_PASSWORD
DOCKER_DEPLOY_EMAIL
EOF

if [ $i -gt 0 ]; then
  echo $i
  echo "exiting"
  exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Good Day Everyone.
I've personally used this method in my bash scripts. Verified works on bash 4.4 and later in Ubuntu, openSUSE, and ClearLinux.

Can RHEL|CentOS|Alma and Arch Based users let me know it it works fine for you?

```
( [ "$VAR1""$VAR2""$VAR3""$VAR4""$VAR5" ] && echo -e " Warning: StackIsNotClear" ) || { echo -e " GoodNews:  StackIsClear"; }
```