# BASH Shell variable interpolation - without eval or creating a new variable

Tags: bash, shell, variables, dynamic, string-interpolation

**bash --version**

```
GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
```

Run the following and I'm wondering if there are any other cool ways to print / get the values (than using eval / requiring to create another variable).

```
a=giga; 
b=$a; 
echo a=$a --equals-- b=$b; 
echo; 

c=\$a; 
eval d_${a}_version=1.1.1;      ## I want to use this format. Use case: where possible values for 'a' are more than 100 and I don't want to create 100+ individual variables in my script.

echo c=$c; 
eval echo "c\'s \(dereferenced_value\)=$c";     ## Had to use eval to de-reference / get to a's value.
echo "d_giga_version = $(eval echo \$d_${a}_version)"; 

d_real_ver=d_${a}_version;                      ## Had to create another variable (wondering if there's another way to dereference d_giga_version variable's value.
echo "d_real_ver     = ${!d_real_ver}";

echo -e "\n\n-- HOW can i get value of 'c' == "giga" without using eval --OR--\n-- How can i get the value '1.1.1' (without requiring to create another new variable like \${d_real_ver}?\n\n"
```

It'll output:

```
a=giga --equals-- b=giga

c=$a
c's (dereferenced_value)=giga
d_giga_version = 1.1.1
d_real_ver     = 1.1.1


-- HOW can i get value of 'c' == giga without using eval --OR--
-- How can i get the value '1.1.1' (without requiring to create another new variable like ${d_real_ver}?
```

**PS**: My post/question that I'm trying to achieve is different than [Bash - variable variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757380/bash-variable-variables) this post uses another variable to derefernece (see last 2 lines in output) for my questions.

Comment: Do you have Bash 4 or newer? If so, you should use associative arrays.

Comment: @BenjaminW. thx I just updated it.

Comment: The second duplicate shows how to use associative arrays.

Comment: how can I pass `echo $c` (which gives '$a' as output) to another echo command using `|` pipe. I mean, if I `touch \$a` (which creates a `$a` named file and do `echo $c | xargs ls -l` it list `$a` file successfully as `-rw-r--r-- 1 112233 group_automation 0 Jan  9 22:06 $a`

It seems like, my question could be how to do this ^^^^ by using `echo` on the output of $c which is '$a' like xargs worked for `ls -l`!!

Comment: @BenjaminW. I like that 2nd post it has a lot of info to learn. Thanks

Comment: ok did that DAMN thing... here:

`echo $c | xargs -I {} sh -c 'echo {}' ` it will spit `giga` (without using `eval` and without using any other variable (at least visually)`).. now I can eat or sleep good! and now I can't even post this solution as the valid answer.

Comment: @ArunSangal, That `echo $c | xargs -I {} sh -c 'echo {}'` won't return any output unless the the variables are exported first.  Example: `a=foo b=$a c=\$a ; echo $c | xargs -I {} sh -c 'echo {}'` returns nothing.  But `export a=foo b=$a c=\$a ; echo $c | xargs -I {} sh -c 'echo {}'` returns *"foo"*.

Comment: @agc thanks, I recall I did that during my hit-trial.