# Parameter expansion for array elements in a loop

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to check if all the environment variables are defined.

Test for individual element works fine as defined below:

```
[ -z ${env_var1:+y} ] && echo "Env var not defined."
```

Although I need to check this for multiple elements, hence want to add it in the loop. But somehow it is not working:

```
env_var_array=( env_var1 env_var2 env_var3 )
for element in "${env_var_array[@]}"
do
  [ -z ${element:+y} ] && echo "$element var not defined."
done
```

It is not working as expected.

Comment: By construction, `element` in your code is one of the strings _env_var1_ and so on. Of course `$element` is always defined. Hence `${elements:+y} always expands to _y_. But in any case: You ask for testing the existence of **environment** variables only, but your code seems to be targeted to **any** bash variable, irrespective whether or not it is in the environment. I think you should clarify this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use [variable variable names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757380/bash-variable-variables), use `${!element}`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

env_var_array=( env_var1 env_var2 env_var3 )
for element in "${env_var_array[@]}"
do
  [ -z "${!element:+y}" ] && echo "$element var not defined."
done
```

```
env_var1 var not defined.
env_var2 var not defined.
env_var3 var not defined.
```

---

Regarding the `:+y` part:

> **`${parameter:+word}`**
>
> If parameter is null or unset, nothing is substituted, otherwise the expansion of word is substituted.
> [[docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)]

Those are not needed in your case, so you can simplfy it to just `[ -z ${!element} ]`

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to check is that all your environment variables are set, this can be done without a loop like this:

```sh
if declare -p "${env_var_array[@]}" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
  printf 'All of these variables are defined: %s\n' "${env_var_array[*]}"
fi
```